# specify taggable type on acts-as-taggable-on rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

So here's the deal, I've been using acts-as-taggable-on on my models but at one point during my application, I had to pull out the models and put them in a gem, so that can I re-use them on several applications that share the structure. The thing is that my gem references the namespaced models IE.

```
VideoapiModel::Category.new
```

or

```
VideoapiModel::Video.new
```

rather than just the model itself ( as it was before)

```
Video.new
```

or

```
Category.new
```

My problem is that now the data that i had before it's "corrupt" because when I use the .tag_list method it would search for taggings with the taggable_type of **VideoapiModel::Video** instead of just **Video** as it was before.

therefor, my question is: **Is there a way to specify the taggable_type on the tags query when using acts-as-taggable-on?**

Comment: Why wouldn't you just update all the taggings to have taggable_type be whatever the name of the model is now?

Comment: @MrTheWalrus I'm trying to avoid manipulating the data directly, and in case of future events like this something happens, it can be changed directly in the code w/o having to go to the database...